# SELECT of mySQL does not show inputs from JSP, only display inputs from mySQL

Tags: mysql, jsp

I need help. I am still new to JSP and mySQL. I know I should not use scriptlet, but this is not the problem I want to ask.Here is the problem. Select query only returns inputs from mySQL, not from JSP. Since I am new to jsp and database, and since the error seems strange, I do not know how to fix the problem.

When I run the register.jsp, and I use the following inputs. "aaa" for username, bbb for password, ccc for email ( all are strings )

mySQL does show this record

```
name     password       email
aaa      bbb            ccc
```

Nevertheless, when I perform in mySQL editor:

```
select * from person where name='aaa';
```

It returns null / null / null

If I type

```
INSERT INTO person VALUES ( 'ppp', 'ooo', 'qqq' )
```

mySQL now shows this record

```
name     password       email
aaa      bbb            ccc
ppp      ooo            qqq
```

when I perform in mySQL editor:

```
select * from person where name='ppp';
```

It returns    ppp / ooo / qqq

```
select * from person where name='aaa';
```

It returns null / null / null

register.jsp

```
<form>
    username:  <input type="text" name="username"> <br>
    password: <input type="text" name="password1"> <br>
    <!-- retyped password: <input type="text" name="password2"> <br> -->
    email:      <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
    <!-- name:  <input type="text" name="name"> <br> -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="register">  
     <a href="login.jsp"> login</a> <br>
     </form>

     <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
     <%@ page import="javax.sql.*" %>
     <%
        String email =  request.getParameter("email");
        String username =  request.getParameter("username");
        session.setAttribute("email", email);
        String password = request.getParameter("password1");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true" , "root", "cs160project");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        if ( email != null && username != null && password != null ) {
            String temp1 = " ' " + username + " ' ";
            String temp2 = " ' " + password  + " ' ";
            String temp3 = " ' " + email + " ' ";
            int temp = statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO person values(" + temp1 + "," + temp2 + "," + temp3 + ");" ); 
        out.println("registered successfully");
        }
     %>
```

Comment: I am guessing you have trailing space after `aaa_`. Also, can you add your JSP code here?

Comment: You are right, thank you so much, I have spent 2 hours on thinking of this problem.